# Issue with django-celery Not running at specific time

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat, djcelery

I am having issues with django-celery not running at the time specified, but it's always runnning every 1 minute. Below I have pasted the tasks.py, settings.py and celery.py. I have tested with djcelery and as well as celery. I am using celery-beat.

celery.py (edited to only give specific and avoid confidential info.):-

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta



# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'netadc.settings')

app = Celery('netadc')
app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='redis://',
             backend='redis://',
             include=['standalone.tasks'])



CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "runs-every-30-seconds": {
        "task": "tasks.cron_span",
        "schedule": 30.0,
        "args": ()
    },
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

settings.py :-

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'ivpn',
    'nsp',
    'lib',
    'ciscoaci',
    'standalone',
    'arista',
    'spa',
    'inet',
    #'django_countries',
    'djcelery',
    #'debug_toolbar',
    'celery',
    'django_celery_beat',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'netadc.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'ivpn.context_processors.vpnreq_info',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                #'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'netadc.wsgi.application'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Phoenix'

USE_TZ = True

## Celery specific settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Phoenix'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

tasks.py :-

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __builtin__ import *
#from future.builtins.disabled import *
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.urls import 
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import json
import os
import requests
import argparse
import collections
import datetime
from django.template import RequestContext
from standalone.forms import UploadFileForm
from django.contrib import messages
#import pyexcel.ext.xls
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import sys, getopt
import StringIO,contextlib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from standalone.views import *
from standalone.models import Fabric, Span
#from celery.decorators import task
from celery import task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery import shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from time import time as time1
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
@task()
def cron_span():
      ########### code #############################
```

I have changed the timezone to be same on all places, and I have also updated the database scheduler using the commands:-
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask
PeriodicTask.objects.update(last_run_at=None)

Any help would be appreciated.

celery logs:-

```
[2018-03-18 11:09:55,078: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,001: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task standalone.tasks.cron_span (standalone.tasks.cron_span)
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,003: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: standalone.tasks.cron_span[707c0da7-d76b-4c4d-92a4-3839f5cd6527]  
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,005: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] where are we
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,011: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] each_all_values
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,011: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] <type 'datetime.datetime'>
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,011: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] each_all_values.time_span
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] <type 'float'>
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] present_time
[2018-03-18 11:10:00,013: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task standalone.tasks.cron_span[707c0da7-d76b-4c4d-92a4-3839f5cd6527] raised unexpected: ValueError('invalid literal for float(): 2018-03-12 21:22:05',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-4.1.0-py2.7.egg/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-4.1.0-py2.7.egg/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/workspace/netadc/standalone/tasks.py", line 57, in cron_span
    time_taken = present_time - float(each_all_values.time_span.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # time_taken is in seconds
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2018-03-12 21:22:05



[2018-03-18 11:11:00,001: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task standalone.tasks.cron_span (standalone.tasks.cron_span)
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,004: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: standalone.tasks.cron_span[23928119-c93a-41c5-9bc7-e2c909324b6f]  
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,005: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] where are we
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] each_all_values
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] <type 'datetime.datetime'>
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] each_all_values.time_span
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,012: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] <type 'float'>
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,013: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] present_time
[2018-03-18 11:11:00,014: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-5] Task standalone.tasks.cron_span[23928119-c93a-41c5-9bc7-e2c909324b6f] raised unexpected: ValueError('invalid literal for float(): 2018-03-12 21:22:05',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-4.1.0-py2.7.egg/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-4.1.0-py2.7.egg/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/workspace/netadc/standalone/tasks.py", line 57, in cron_span
    time_taken = present_time - float(each_all_values.time_span.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # time_taken is in seconds
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2018-03-12 21:22:05
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the task every 30 seconds, then you should do:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "runs-every-30-seconds": {
        "task": "tasks.cron_span",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
        "args": ()
    },
}
```

for old celery versions.

Comment: Do you say the task is running every min? can you post the celery logs?

Comment: updated my original question with celery logs.. command used celery -A netadc worker --beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

Comment: Yes it's running every minute despite specifying a time.

Comment: Please, go to the console and type `from django.conf import settings;settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` to check which is the exact value there

Comment: I get an error:-
ImportError: No module named djago.conf
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE'

Comment: it is `from django.conf import settings`, you missed the `n`. It seems you have a wrong reference somewhere in the project, do a search for `djago.conf`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That was the 1st command and then it threw an error. After that, if you see I mentioned "django.conf", and it gives an error that it cannot find CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE..

Comment: That is the problem, you must include `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` in your settings file, not in `celery.py`

Comment: It still does not work :(.. beat schedule seems to run though.
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE
{'runs-every-30-seconds': {'task': 'tasks.cron_span', 'args': (), 'schedule': datetime.timedelta(0, 30)}}

Comment: Did you remove all .pyc, remove `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` from your `celery.py` file  and restarted celery?

Comment: Yes I commented out the CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE from my celery.py and deleted celery.pyc. And restarted the beat service

Comment: I am writing my tasks under tasks.py. However, in the docs they have defined it under celery.py. Is that what may cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False` set in your `settings.py` file, otherwise celery converts your schedules to UTC.